# WebDriver .click() not working, even with ExpectedConditions set

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, junit

I have the following code:

```
WebDriverWait wait;
....

WebElement widget=webDriver.findElement(by);
WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(by));
```

I have also tried ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated and presenceOfElementLocated
I get the same result every time, the click() happens but too soon, and it does not register. If I use Thread.sleep() prior to the click then it works as expected. This seems like a horrible solution so I am looking for something else. The best I could come up with is a loop as such:

```
while(!conditionThatIsTrueWhenClickHappens) {
     el.click();
}
```

Any suggestions are much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What are you clicking on? Can we see the html?

Comment: @Dax, if you let us in on what the html looks like we can probably help a lot faster.